# Is a simple `if` faster than `else if` when it breaks a loop?

Tags: javascript, performance, loops, if-statement

This might be immeasurable, but I'll still ask. Out of curiosity.

In this code:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  if (i > 5) {
    break;
  }
  
  console.log("Do some stuff:", i);
}
```

I run a loop for 6 iterations and break it on the 7th.

In this code:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  if (i > 5) {
    break;
  } else {
    console.log("Do some stuff:", i);
  }
}
```

I do pretty much the same except the code that runs before the loop is broken is inside an `else` to the `if` that breaks it.

Obviously, the result is the same. However, are those two pieces of code processed differently at a lower level? Is one of them even slightly faster? **Does it make any difference other than looks?**

Comment: It really depends on the VM you are targeting, it could very well using the same instructions for both examples here for one VM but not for another. There's also no concrete answer for the scenario in general, a small context change could make the compiler change the code completely.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax doesn't have performance characteristics. One may suggest that the algorithms in the spec that govern the behavior of the syntax have implied performance characteristics, but that's not necessarily true either.

Especially in the case of modern optimizing compilers, your code is entirely rewritten anyway, so even in some cases where it *looks like* one thing should be actually faster or slower than the other, it may not actually turn out to be.

As with all performance questions, especially in the case of micro-optimizations, benchmarking is the way to make a determination, and even then, the results should be taken with a grain of salt, as real-world code may not reflect the results you observed in the benchmark, in part due to the code re-writing I mentioned above, or also possibly because of flaws in the benchmark test itself.